# Variable not blitting in pygame?

Tags: python, variables, text, pygame, blit

In Pygame, I'm making a game with highscores. I want to blit a highscore variable onto the screen, called `c` but whenever I try to run the program, it freezes and I don't know why. How can I blit the variable `c` to the screen without it freezing? Here is the relevant code:

```
# High score (printed in the corner)

    c=0
    while c>=0:
        c=c+1

    highscore=myfont6.render("High score:",True, THECOLORS["purple"])
    score=myfont6.render(c, True, THECOLORS["purple"])
    screen.blit(highscore, (20,20))
    screen.blit(score,(40,20))
```

Answer (score 3):

It's this chunk right here. Once you hit this chunk of code, your program will continue to loop forever.

```
    c=0
    while c>=0:
        c=c+1
```

I'm guessing you intended to have c increase by one on every loop of the main game loop. If that's the case, just remove the first two lines and call `c += 1` on each main game loop.

Comment: That didn't work. I got the error that c wasn't defined, so I said c=0. When I defined c, I got this error: NameError: name 'c' is not defined

Comment: Try putting c = 0 before your main loop.